# Window/linux path component separating

Tags: java, linux, windows, string, path

I am writing a path separator in my linux environment and it is meant to parse a file path that can be both linux and windows style which I never know before hand. Currently I was splitting using the File.separator but that only works for the platform I am on...

I am looking to know if there is a way to handle this using something like the Path object for example.

```
[...]
Node pathElement = nodeList.item(nodePos);
String path = pathElement.getTextContent();
String[] pathElements = path.split(File.separator);
String contentFileName = pathElements[pathElements.length - 1];
String parentFolderPath = xmlFiles[u].getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
pathElement.setTextContent(parentFolderPath + File.separator + contentFileName);
[...]
```

EDIT: I need to be able to break a windows style path from linux and vice versa. I have also attempted to use `Paths.getPath(...)` unsuccessfully

See a sample output from the above code:

/input/ZIP_0bd78143-f6cd-473f-84f7-d0da09dc42aa/7634/c:\SharedFiles\7634\1

It used the windows path as file name since it wasn't able to break it. I am trying to avoid fancy logic to detect the type of path if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your edits, you might need to detect the FileSystem at a given URI, might want to take a look into this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html

Comment: thats the problem the file separator is bound to the operating system. So if I am on linux trying to break a windows style path I cannot use that property

Comment: The property changes depending on what environment the JVM is running on.  From the documentation on Oracle's website: "Character that separates components of a file path. This is "/" on UNIX and "\" on Windows".  I believe it's not the same as File.separator.

Comment: Just tried it on a linux and windows environment, and it worked.

Comment: Seems like an easy solution.  Just use "\" for a windows path, and "/"  for a UNIX path.